# Disable or change port number for libvirt dnsmasq service on ubuntu host

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm

How can I disable or change the port number for the libvirt dnsmasq service?

I need to make port 53 available on the main host.

❯ sudo lsof -i | grep dns
dnsmasq     2458 libvirt-dnsmasq    3u  IPv4    38663      0t0  UDP *:bootps
dnsmasq     2458 libvirt-dnsmasq    5u  IPv4    38666      0t0  UDP :domain
dnsmasq     2458 libvirt-dnsmasq    6u  IPv4    38667      0t0  TCP :domain (LISTEN)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year, but I just got into same situation.

Open "Virt-Manager", select a connection, then in the menu select Edit, then "Connection Details", it will open a new window. Go to the tab "Virtual Networks". Stop the networks. This will already remove port 53 from listening ports. If needed to start the network, one may add `<dns enable="no">` to the XML (and apply), but the VMs won't connect.

I don't know how to make the VMs connect having dns disabled, in my case I don't need to have the networks started all the time, so, stopping the Virtual Networks is enough for me.